# Incoming Email Server (I think) is Blocking Email Form

Tags: email-server, spam-filter

I’m not a server professional of IT person, so ignorance is admitted in terms of configuring servers. But this is why I am seeking direction from someone who knows more.

When I build websites, it is common enough that the email forms won’t get through to my business clients’ email inboxes. But they will get through to mine, and other email addresses as well.

This is not an issue where the customer’s mail client is sending it to his or her “junk” or “spam” folder. It’s not getting through at all. It seems to be rejected at the server level.

However, the same email WILL arrive in my inbox, in a client’s non-business gmail account, etc. if we’re all sent the email, and, sure enough, the email that arrives has the client’s business email address (the one that is not being received) right there in the “to” field.

*The fact that emails are being generated and sent by the outgoing mail server to ME tells me that the problem is NOT on the outgoing end. It seems to me that the outgoing server is willing to create and send an email from the web form—but that certain INCOMING servers don’t like  something about the email and are blocking it as spam or suspicious.*

**Question 1:** Does this thinking have merit? Or is my assumption one that shouldn’t be made?

**Question 2:** If it does seem reasonable to think that the problem is on the incoming mail server side, can someone point me toward where one would go to sort of “whitelist” the incoming form email as safe? Is this something we call the web host on? Speak to the client’s IT person who sets up the emails? Something that is usually configurable in a control panel from the host?

Not necessarily looking for line-by-line direction on HOW to fix it, but where to go. Before I look for a solution, I've got to know I'm in the right place.

Comment: You go to your mail server's log files.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting is really just common sense. (First, is this only happening with some clients? If so is anything different with their websites? If it's only a few and the sites are cookie cutter then a quick call to their IT manager may solve it fast.)

1. The email addresses work for regular email, yes? Is there a way on the site to send a test message to your client's email? (rather than a form submit, maybe some sort of contact us page with a mailto? or even try some basic html with a mailto) See if that works.
2. If the mailto works then look at the log files to see what's different when the email is generated with a form submit.
3. Make sure the form generated email does not contain any typical "spam words" like Free, Make Money, Credit Check and the like.  You can Google search for the typical blacklisted spam words for email.
4. If all that fails, then talk to the IT staff and describe the situation.

Comment: Thanks, Lena. Nothing is significantly different between any of the clients, and, yes, it only happens for some of them. Some of the sites have emails I'll code through a PHP script, others use Wordpress and form plugins (which, ultimately, would be PHP scripts, too, just set up by other people). 

The emails always work fine for regular email. Basic HTML with mailto always works, because that creates an email that is generated by the local mail client and uses their ISP's email server.

No spam words.

I will see what I can do to check those logs. Thanks for your input!